# JavaScript - replace document.write() with DOM function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am looking for some kind of a custom generic function that would allow me to dynamically create elements with JavaScript/jQuery. Since I am working with XHTML and the `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type, I am forced to work with DOM functions instead of `document.write();`. Take the following fallback code for jQuery:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
    if (!navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/msie\s[5-8]/i)) {
        document.write('<script charset="UTF-8" type="application/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/jquery-2.min.js"><\/script>');
    } else {
        document.write('<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/jquery-1.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
}
```

The browser console will display an error and the code will not be executed. So what I think I need is something like this:

```
function writeXHTML(tag) {
    // some ugly DOM-based code to execute in order for the tag to be created. Support IE, please!
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
    if (!navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/msie\s[5-8]/i)) {
        writeXHTML('<script charset="UTF-8" type="application/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/jquery-2.min.js"><\/script>');
    } else {
        writeXHTML('<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/jquery-1.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
}
```

Obviously, I will need to create the jQuery script in the `<head>`, before the other `<script>`s that depend on it. And I would also need this to be done from an external script since I don't like inlin-ing :P
I guess I could use `id`s to do that, but what code should the `writeXHTML();` function have? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Google loader instead. https://developers.google.com/loader/

Comment: Yes I have thought of using Google CDN, but there are still some countries that have blacklisted/blocked Google's domain. Obviously my site is not targeting Chinese visitors, so I might reconsider using Google Loader.